# ”Undefined offset: 4” when reindexing “Search indexer”

Tags: magento2, reindex, magento-2.2.5, indexing

After module update I've got such error for indexing via SSH

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /home/sellastu/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/Full.php on line 384
```

[image]

Now, when I'm trying to enter any product page I've got such result:

[image]

But I can enter any other places on the site. All static pages, catalogue, checkout, admin etc.

[image]

This line is located in system.log file:

```
[2018-11-07 17:13:10] main.ERROR: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid has an error: Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /home/sellastu/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/Full.php on line 384. Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":121634816,"emalloc_start":115599216} [] []
```

I tried to remove all static files, restore database, which was created before module update, and still have the same problem. Does anyone know what to do next?

Comment: Got the same problem... Anyone have a solution?

Comment: What was the name on your extension?

Answer (score 0):

it's probably still some eav values still in the entity tables. 
You can try install [EAV Cleaner](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/tree/magento2) and run command `eav:attributes:remove-unused`